# How to conditionally move only items with numbers from one array to another array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am looking for some help figuring out how to check my array for any element with a number, and then moving those items into another array.

```
    var array = ["January 2018", "Item One", "Item Two", "December 2017"],
    array2 = [];
    if(
      //array item contains a number 
    ){
    //array item with number move to array2
    }
```

`array` is not acctually hard coded.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a new array which contains elements with numbers and remove those from the initial array.

```js
 var array = ["January 2018", "Item One", "Item Two", "December 2017"];
 var numbersArray = array.filter(function(item, idx){
    var regx = /\d/g; 
    regx.test(item) && array.splice(idx, 1);
   
    return regx.test(item);
 });
 
 console.log(array);
 console.log(numbersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["January 2018", "Item One", "Item Two", "December 2017"];

// Make new array containing only the elements that have digits
var array2 = array.filter( x => /\d/.test(x) );

console.log( array2 );
```